# How to create a composite Key Field in Apache Solr?

Tags: java, solr

I have an Apache Solr 3.5 setup that has a SchemaXml like this:

```
<field name="appid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="docid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

What I would need is a field that concatenates them together and uses that as `<uniqueKey>`. There seems nothing built-in, short of creating a multi-valued `id` field and using `<copyField>`, but it seems uniqueKey requires a single-valued field.

The only reason I need this is to allow clients to blindly fire `<add>` calls and have Solr figure out if it's an addition or update. Therefore, I don't care too much *how* the ID looks like.

I assume I would have to write my own Analyzer or Tokenizer? I'm just starting out learning Solr, so I'm not 100% sure what I'd actually need and would appreciate any hints towards what I need to implement.

Comment: I not sure how the java api handle the add or update of docs, but it should be :- if an ID found = update doc, else insert doc. So, I guess the ID does matter ...

Comment: @ajreal Yes, that's what Solr does if a uniqueKey is specified. The thing is that my Unique ID is composed of two different IDs, and I want to move the burden of properly creating that composite ID away from the application developer and into the search server.

Comment: @MichaelStum have you tried my solution? May I know what you think?

Comment: @javanna Haven't had a chance yet, but I'm going back to the Solr project this or next week. Sorry for the delay, at a glance it looks like the right stuff though.

Comment: @MichaelStum No worries, just let me know how it went and if you need help. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally give that burden to the users, since it's pretty easy for them adding a field to each document.

Otherwise, you would have to write a few lines of code I guess. You could write your own [`UpdateRequestProcessorFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) which adds the new field automatically to every input document based on the value of other existing fields. You can use a separator and keep it single value. 
On your `UpdateRequestProcessor` you should override the `processAdd` method like this:

```
@Override
public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    SolrInputDocument doc = cmd.getSolrInputDocument();
    String appid = (String)doc.getFieldValue( "appid" );
    String docid = (String)doc.getFieldValue( "docid" );
    doc.addField("uniqueid", appid + "-" + docid);    
    // pass it up the chain
    super.processAdd(cmd);
}
```

Then you should add your `UpdateProcessor` to your customized `updateRequestProcessorChain` as the first processor in the chain (`solrconfig.xml`):

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="mychain" >
    <processor class="my.package.MyUpdateRequestProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Hope it works, I haven't tried it. I already did something like this but not with uniqueKey or required fields, that's the only problem you could find. But I guess if you put the updateProcessor at the beginning of the chain, it should work.

Comment: Finally got around trying it out, and although I just skimmed over it, the approach seemed to have worked. Thanks again!